# suggestion for ordinal regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, ordinal

I am evaluating how much the method B for data collection, predicts the method A.

It’s important to SAY that METHOD A has HIERARCHY data (on a scale ranging from 0 to 3) and METHOD B has data with CONTINUOUS VALUES.

The problem is that when I got a warning message in the model summary and many summary statistics are missing. Does anyone have any suggestions in for clmm or any other ordinal model?

Here is just a example of my data

```js
data_model1$method_A=factor(data_model1$lek, levels=0:3, ordered = T)
dput(data_model1)
mod = clmm(method_A~method_B*species+(1|laandscape/Informant), data=data_model1, Hess=T)
summary(mod)
```

```html
 Informant  laandscape  species method_A    method_B
    Namea   AA  Cheracebus_lucifer  2   0.000
    Namea   AA  Cuniculus_paca  3   0.000
    Namea   AA  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   1   0.000
    Namea   AA  Dasypus_novemcinctus    2   0.000
    Namea   AA  Didelphis_marsupialis   3   0.000
    Namea   AA  Eira_barbara    2   0.552
    Namea   AA  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   1   0.004
    Namea   AA  Lagothrix_lagotricha    2   0.000
    Namea   AA  Leontocebus_nigricollis 2   0.035
    Namea   AA  Leopardus_pardalis  2   0.000
    Namea   AA  Lontra_longicaudis  2   0.000
    Nameb   AA  Cheracebus_lucifer  1   0.004
    Nameb   AA  Cuniculus_paca  1   0.000
    Nameb   AA  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   3   0.313
    Nameb   AA  Dasypus_novemcinctus    1   1.030
    Nameb   AA  Didelphis_marsupialis   0   0.000
    Nameb   AA  Eira_barbara    0   0.000
    Nameb   AA  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   0   0.000
    Nameb   AA  Lagothrix_lagotricha    3   0.004
    Nameb   AA  Leontocebus_nigricollis 3   0.000
    Nameb   AA  Leopardus_pardalis  2   0.000
    Nameb   AA  Lontra_longicaudis  2   0.000
    Namec   AA  Cheracebus_lucifer  2   0.000
    Namec   AA  Cuniculus_paca  1   0.000
    Namec   AA  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   1   0.552
    Namec   AA  Dasypus_novemcinctus    1   0.004
    Namec   AA  Didelphis_marsupialis   2   0.000
    Namec   AA  Eira_barbara    2   0.035
    Namec   AA  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   2   0.000
    Namec   AA  Lagothrix_lagotricha    3   0.000
    Namec   AA  Leontocebus_nigricollis 3   0.004
    Namec   AA  Leopardus_pardalis  0   0.000
    Namec   AA  Lontra_longicaudis  0   0.313
    Named   BB  Cheracebus_lucifer  0   1.030
    Named   BB  Cuniculus_paca  0   0.000
    Named   BB  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   3   0.000
    Named   BB  Dasypus_novemcinctus    3   0.000
    Named   BB  Didelphis_marsupialis   2   0.004
    Named   BB  Eira_barbara    2   0.000
    Named   BB  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   2   0.552
    Named   BB  Lagothrix_lagotricha    0   0.004
    Named   BB  Leontocebus_nigricollis 0   0.000
    Namee   BB  Cheracebus_lucifer  0   0.035
    Namee   BB  Cuniculus_paca  0   0.000
    Namee   BB  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   3   0.000
    Namee   BB  Dasypus_novemcinctus    3   0.004
    Namee   BB  Didelphis_marsupialis   2   0.000
    Namee   BB  Eira_barbara    2   0.313
    Namee   BB  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   2   1.030
    Namee   BB  Lagothrix_lagotricha    2   0.000
    Namee   BB  Leontocebus_nigricollis 2   0.000
    Namef   BB  Cheracebus_lucifer  2   0.000
    Namef   BB  Cuniculus_paca  2   0.004
    Namef   BB  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   2   0.000
    Namef   BB  Dasypus_novemcinctus    2   0.000
    Namef   BB  Didelphis_marsupialis   1   0.000
    Namef   BB  Eira_barbara    1   0.552
    Namef   BB  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   1   0.004
    Namef   BB  Lagothrix_lagotricha    1   0.000
    Namef   BB  Leontocebus_nigricollis 3   0.035
    Nameg   CC  Cheracebus_lucifer  0   0.000
    Nameg   CC  Cuniculus_paca  3   0.000
    Nameg   CC  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   3   0.004
    Nameg   CC  Dasypus_novemcinctus    3   0.000
    Nameg   CC  Didelphis_marsupialis   3   0.313
    Nameg   CC  Eira_barbara    3   1.030
    Nameg   CC  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   3   0.000
    Nameg   CC  Lagothrix_lagotricha    2   0.000
    Nameg   CC  Leontocebus_nigricollis 2   0.000
    Nameh   CC  Cheracebus_lucifer  2   0.004
    Nameh   CC  Cuniculus_paca  2   0.000
    Nameh   CC  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   2   0.552
    Nameh   CC  Dasypus_novemcinctus    2   0.004
    Nameh   CC  Didelphis_marsupialis   2   0.000
    Nameh   CC  Eira_barbara    2   0.035
    Nameh   CC  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   1   0.000
    Nameh   CC  Lagothrix_lagotricha    1   0.000
    Nameh   CC  Leontocebus_nigricollis 1   0.004
    Namei   CC  Cheracebus_lucifer  1   0.000
    Namei   CC  Cuniculus_paca  2   0.313
    Namei   CC  Dasyprocta_fuliginosa   2   1.030
    Namei   CC  Dasypus_novemcinctus    3   0.000
    Namei   CC  Didelphis_marsupialis   3   0.000
    Namei   CC  Eira_barbara    3   0.000
    Namei   CC  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   3   0.004
    Namei   CC  Lagothrix_lagotricha    3   0.000
    Namei   CC  Leontocebus_nigricollis 2   0.313
    Namej   DD  Dasypus_novemcinctus    2   1.030
    Namej   DD  Didelphis_marsupialis   2   0.000
    Namej   DD  Eira_barbara    2   0.000
    Namej   DD  Hydrochoerus_hydrochaeris   2   0.000
```

Comment: You have `Informnt` in your model.  Should that be `Informant`?  And what's your warning message?  Please `dput()` your data rather than just printing it.  Help us to help you...

Comment: I have corrected the ''informant'', but the problem is not there. I have dput() the data.